# Can developer retrieve customer's Windows Error Report?

Tags: windows, windows-error-reporting

I am working on developing a desktop package application that runs on Windows 10.

On the following page of Wikipedia, under Third-party software, it says the following

> Software & hardware manufacturers may access their error reports using
> Microsoft's Windows Dev Center Hardware and Desktop Dashboard
> (formerly Winqual) program."
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Error_Reporting

I interpreted this to mean that I can see the WERs that Microsft collects from my customers' PCs.
But I don't know how to do that.

I found a Microsoft document that might be relevant, but it's old, from 2007.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/empower/introducing-windows-error-reporting

Is the service now discontinued?

If I can get the WER, it will be very useful to identify the cause of the product crash.

Comment: I found a document that might be useful.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/appxpkg/windows-desktop-application-program

Comment: Is your app signed with a proper certificate?

Comment: Thank you. The installer and certification is not my team's job, but I think it is.
I found the above document, so I will consult with my team members based on it.